# Enable AutoArchive capability on Outlook client when Exchange mailbox has In-Place Archiving enabled

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, archiving

Any way to enable the AutoArchive (Manual Archival) feature on an Outlook client when the Exchange Mailbox configured in the client has In-Place Archiving enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook's autoarchive moves stuff to PST. Is that what you really want?

If you've archive-enabled a mailbox you can use retention policies in Exchange to manage how and when mailbox content is automatically shifted from the primary mailbox to the archive mailbox.